# Python3: Sorting a list of tuples by datastamp contained in first element of tuple

Tags: python, sorting

I'm having difficulty in using sort in python.

Basically, I have a list like this, containing tuples that have a String and a Dictionary.
The string is the name and contains a timestamp of the format '%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss'

Example:

```
[
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-12_05h14m58s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-12_05h14m58s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h53m27s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h53m27s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h49m26s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h49m26s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h50m27s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h50m27s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h50m54s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h50m54s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example2_2020-05-11_10h23m09s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example2_2020-05-11_10h23m09s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example2_2020-05-11_10h22m37s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example2_2020-05-11_10h22m37s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ]
]
```

I'd like this list to be sorted according to the timestamp, preferably with the most recent one being the first element.

I have been trying to do so through the sorted() method of Python but getting stuck.
It will probably be a combination of regex and a lambda function but I have not managed to get it to work.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Not very important, but that's a list of lists, not tuples.

Comment: if first element in list is the same string and only `2020-05-11_11h50m27s.` is different then normal `new_list = sorted(list, reverse=True)` or `list.sort(reverse=True)` should sort it as expected.

Comment: if text is different but  `2020-05-11_11h50m27` is in the same place then you can use slicing `text[start:end]`  and `key=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have date and time in the same place in string so you can use slicing to get it and compare without converting to timestamp.

```
data = [ ... your data ...] 

for item in data:
    print(item[0][-25:-5])
```

Gives

```
2020-05-12_05h14m58s
2020-05-11_11h53m27s
2020-05-11_11h49m26s
2020-05-11_11h50m27s
2020-05-11_11h50m54s
2020-05-11_10h23m09s
2020-05-11_10h22m37s
```

So you can use `key=` with slicing

```
data = sorted(data, reverse=True, key=lambda item:item[0][-25:-5])
```

---

Full example

```
data = [
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-12_05h14m58s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-12_05h14m58s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h53m27s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h53m27s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h49m26s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h49m26s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h50m27s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h50m27s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h50m54s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example_2020-05-11_11h50m54s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example2_2020-05-11_10h23m09s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example2_2020-05-11_10h23m09s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ],
    [
      "/lfs_store/history/snapshot_stack_instance_document_example2_2020-05-11_10h22m37s.json",
      {
        "category": "history",
        "description": "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
        "name": "stack_instance_document_example2_2020-05-11_10h22m37s",
        "type": "snapshot"
      }
    ]
]

#for item in data:
#    print(item[0][-25:-5])

data = sorted(data, reverse=True, key=lambda item:item[0][-25:-5])

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `key` that you can use:

```
def date_key(t):
    path, info = t
    date_regex = r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}h\d{2}m\d{2}s"
    m = re.search(date_regex, path)
    date = m.group(0)
    return date
```

And then:

```
xs.sort(key=date_key)
```